# Unable to display detail view using .json file

Tags: angular

I have a photo gallery app that works fine when im pulling data from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. But when i use my own local data it breaks when I click on a photo to go to the detail view. How can the photos display but then give me a 404 error when I click on one to go to detail view? Here is my code:

```
export class DataService {

     private _url: string = '/assets/data/img.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getUsers(){
    return this.http.get(this._url);
}
getUser(id){
    const url = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
}


}
```

And detail view path

```
{
    path: 'details/:id',
    component: DetailsComponent
  },
```

And a snippet of my json data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "category": "offense",
  "caption": "No chance!",
  "imageUrl": "https://placeimg.com/200/200/arch"
},
```

Detail component:

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    singleItem$: Object;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {

      this.route.params.subscribe(params => this.singleItem$ = params.id)
   }

  ngOnInit() {

      this.data.getUser(this.singleItem$).subscribe(data => this.singleItem$ = data)
  }

}
```

angular.json

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
```

Again the only thing I change is the _url string to: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos and the app works as intended.

Comment: remove src/, just assets. also, private _url: string = 'assets/data/i....

Answer (score 0):

Your getUser() function adds the item's index to the URL.

```
getUser(id){
    const url = `${this._url}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

So if you're fetching the data for Id 1, the request url would be '/assets/data/img.json/1', which can't be loaded.

For test, you could load the entire data from the local json file and select the required photo when you subscribe to it.

```
// Data Service
getUser(id){
    //const url = `${this._url}/${id}`; /* Get the URL to json */
    return this.http.get(url);
}

// DetailsComponent 
ngOnInit() {
  this.data.getUser(this.singleItem$).subscribe(data => this.singleItem$ = data.find(x => x.id === this.singleItem$))
}
```